# Issues With Integer 0 When Multiplying Infinite Integer java

Tags: java, integer, multiplication, infinite

I have this really strange issue with my program where whenever I multiply a negative number by 0, the answer shows up as "-0". This happens whether 0 is the first or second number in the operation. For example, if I were to multiply -500 and 0, -0 would be the answer that shows up. I am not sure why this is doing this.

```
public InfiniteIntegerInterface multiply(final InfiniteIntegerInterface anInfiniteInteger)
    {
            // TO DO
        int place1 = 0;
        int place2 = 0;
        LInfiniteInteger tempFirstOp = new LInfiniteInteger(this.toString());
        LInfiniteInteger tempSecondOp = new LInfiniteInteger(anInfiniteInteger.toString());
        LInfiniteInteger firstOperand = new LInfiniteInteger("");
        LInfiniteInteger secondOperand = new LInfiniteInteger("");
        LInfiniteInteger result = new LInfiniteInteger("");
        LInfiniteInteger tempResult = new LInfiniteInteger("");
        String tempResultString = "";
        Integer tempResultInt = new Integer(0);
        if((tempFirstOp.compareTo(tempSecondOp) == 1) || (tempFirstOp.compareTo(tempSecondOp) == 0))
        {
            firstOperand = tempFirstOp;
            secondOperand = tempSecondOp;
        }
        else
        {
            firstOperand = tempSecondOp;
            secondOperand = tempFirstOp;
        }

        Node currentTwo = secondOperand.lastNode;
    if ((firstOperand.isNegative == true) && (secondOperand.isNegative == false)) {
        while(currentTwo != null)
        {
            place1 = 0;
            Node currentOne = firstOperand.lastNode;
            while(currentOne != null)
            {
                tempResultInt = currentOne.data * currentTwo.data;
                tempResultString = tempResultInt.toString();
                for(int i = 0; i < (place1 + place2); i++)
                {
                    tempResultString = tempResultString + "0";
                }
                tempResult = new LInfiniteInteger(tempResultString);
                result = new LInfiniteInteger(result.plus(tempResult).toString());
                place1++;
                currentOne = currentOne.previous;
            }
            place2++;
            currentTwo = currentTwo.previous;
        }
     result.isNegative = true;
        return result; 
    }  
    if ((firstOperand.isNegative == false) && (secondOperand.isNegative == true)) {
        while(currentTwo != null)
        {
            place1 = 0;
            Node currentOne = firstOperand.lastNode;
            while(currentOne != null)
            {
                tempResultInt = currentOne.data * currentTwo.data;
                tempResultString = tempResultInt.toString();
                for(int i = 0; i < (place1 + place2); i++)
                {
                    tempResultString = tempResultString + "0";
                }
                tempResult = new LInfiniteInteger(tempResultString);
                result = new LInfiniteInteger(result.plus(tempResult).toString());
                place1++;
                currentOne = currentOne.previous;
            }
            place2++;
            currentTwo = currentTwo.previous;
        }
     result.isNegative = true;
        return result; 
    }   

    else {
        while(currentTwo != null)
        {
            place1 = 0;
            Node currentOne = firstOperand.lastNode;
            while(currentOne != null)
            {
                tempResultInt = currentOne.data * currentTwo.data;
                tempResultString = tempResultInt.toString();
                for(int i = 0; i < (place1 + place2); i++)
                {
                    tempResultString = tempResultString + "0";
                }
                tempResult = new LInfiniteInteger(tempResultString);
                result = new LInfiniteInteger(result.plus(tempResult).toString());
                place1++;
                currentOne = currentOne.previous;
            }
            place2++;
            currentTwo = currentTwo.previous;
        }

        return result; 
    }   


  }
```

Comment: Any specific reason you are creating your own integral class instead of using Java's built in BigInteger? The basic problem you are facing is that 0 is by definition not positive or negative so your code should include an isZero() and add `if` statements for those cases... Very ineficient...

Comment: We have to use the class for this assignment, but I like the isZero() idea for the code. Thanks!

Comment: you could also just assume 0 to be positive (even though that it not mathematically correct) and do a check in the right at the end op applying an operation, ie. when isNegative() for zero -> make sure `-0` is replaced by 0.